# How do I authenticate wired connections over my router's ethernet port?

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have an internet connection from ISP which I connect through a D-Link router. The router logs into the ISP's PPPoE connection using the credentials given by the ISP to me and I have setup a Wireless network with my own SSID & password. The router also has multiple ethernet ports which I use to connect the devices sitting close to the router. What I wonder is that anyone without any authentication can connect to the network using these ethernet ports on the router.

My router is kept in a location mostly unsupervised. Anyone willing to connect their own laptop to the network can do it without my permission. I want to avoid this. Is there a way I can protect my wired connection? Something similar to putting a password to my wifi, I want a password for my wired connection as well, if possible one which is remembered by my client device like the wifi passwords.

I have already thought of one way, which is removing the PPPoE settings from my router and using the ISP credentials directly on the client browser which has the following cons:

- I will have to manually login using ISP credentials every time on every device, even though it is connected over wifi. This creates 2 steps of authentication on every connect which is kind of an overkill for a small home network setup.
- Whenever I need to share the network with a guest, I will have to provide them my ISP credentials as well to connect to the network along with the wireless network authentication details, which I do not want to do.

I only want to make sure that if any new device is connected to the router using ethernet port, it must be authenticated somehow using some credentials. Even if it is a simplest id-password type protocol authentication, it would be sufficient as I am looking at securing the network from unsupervised access of just another guy walking near the router rather than from hackers or network security experts.

Comment: You won’t be able to do anything about this with a consumer-grade router. It’s probably easier to get a secure cabinet for the router. Keep in mind that it shouldn’t be metal because of Wi-Fi.

Comment: You may be able to use MAC filtering. It's not completely secure but it might be good enough for your needs. See [access control - Security provided through MAC filtering: Wired vs. Wireless Networks - Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/security-provided-through-mac-filtering-wired-vs-wireless-networks)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a "whitelist" of devices allowed to connect to the router, using
MAC addresses to identify the device. I've never encountered a home router that lacked
that function.

Comment: This will screen out most visitors.  However, some devices can spoof MAC addresses.

Answer (score 0):

In "enterprise" routers and switches, this would be done using 802.1X – which works almost exactly like WPA-Enterprise and often uses the same underlying software. (There is no direct equivalent for WPA-Personal, although some switches/routers can use a built-in account list instead of requiring a dedicated RADIUS server.)

In less capable routers, the ports could be placed in a separate VLAN, and the firewall configured to prevent that VLAN from having any network access at all. This could even be used to implement browser-based "captive portal" login systems. (Or the ports could be disabled outright.)

However, your D-Link probably does not support either of those things and I think your remaining options are entirely physical: put the router in a box, or glue the Ethernet ports shut.